# How to store the result of SQL query in Session Variable using ASP.NET C# to use it later

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am new to ASP.NET C#, I am working to develop web forms to send and receive messages (SQL Server as database) like emails. I want to store the result of SQL query in Session Variable and use it later in another page.

Kindly help me how can I do that, please correct if any things goes wrong.

Here is my code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=AZEEM\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=kics;User ID=sa;Password=123");
con.Open();

String query = "select username as sender,subject,message from emailtable where receiver='" + Session["username"] + "'";

    enter code here

//this is the query for which I want to store the result in variable myvar, how can I store the result of following query in variable myvar and use it later, when  I execute it, string is shown instead of result of string.
String myvar = "select receiver from emailtable where username='" + Session["username"] + "'";
SqlDataReader reader = null;

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(myvar, con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
sda.Fill(dt);
reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

ds = myvar;
```

Comment: ,whiat is your qst actually, clarify more

Comment: actually I want to store the result of the following query in variable myvar,String myvar = "select receiver from emailtable where username='" + Session["username"] + "'"; I dont know how to do it, when i check the result of this query, it gives me query string but i want result of query.

Answer (score 1):

Try below,

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=AZEEM\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=kics;User ID=sa;Password=123");
con.Open();

String query = "select username as sender,subject,message from emailtable where receiver='" + Session["username"] + "'";

    enter code here

//this is the query for which I want to store the result in variable myvar, how can I store the result of following query in variable myvar and use it later, when  I execute it, string is shown instead of result of string.
String myvar = "select receiver from emailtable where username='" + Session["username"] + "'";
SqlDataReader reader = null;

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(myvar, con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
sda.Fill(dt);
reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();

session["dt"] = dt;
```

When you retrieve,

```
if (session["dt"] != null) {
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)session["dt"];
}
```

Comment: OP problem is different . _actually I want to store the result of the following query in variable myvar,String myvar = "select receiver from emailtable where username='" + Session["username"] + "'"; I dont know how to do it, when i check the result of this query, it gives me query string but i want result of query_ , so i dont think this is what OP is asking

Comment: You mean, you just want to store string in session, please see my updated answer.

Comment: two points i will clarify you, I'm not the OP , 2. you are understanding the Problem in a wrong way

Comment: Well, first I understand that you want to store result of your query, so definitely that will be in datatable. So I saved whole datatable in session. But as per your recent comment, you told that you want to store your variable. So I saved it within session. If you are looking something different, please let me know.

Comment: i am not the original Poster (OP ) of this Question

Comment: @Webruster explain me original problem as you wrote in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to Pass that Query to this Method which will return you the result Set and then try to assign it to the Session

```
    String myvar = "select receiver from emailtable where username='" +  Session["username"] + "'";
    Session["myvar"] = GetData(myvar);
```

Method for **GetData** as Follows

```
   private static DataTable GetData(string query)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string constr = "Data Source=AZEEM\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=kics;User ID=sa;Password=123";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        sda.Fill(dt);

                    }
                }
                return dt;
            }
        }
```